# missing "&" AND "enumerate numbering" by using "MnSymbol" and "babel"

Tags: babel, mnsymbol

I 'm using `MnSymbol`package (for the `uparrowtail`) and also `babel` package (for text). The problem is that:

- the "&" symbol disappeared and
- the numberin in `enumerate` environment disappered,

as you can see below.

[image]

The `log`-file is [here](https://pastebin.com/QWphyv3x), and the code is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}

Κείμενο 1 \& κείμενο 2.

\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
    \item κείμενο 1
    \item κείμενο 2
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

How can I fix it?

**Thanks in advanced!**

Comment: @Kώστας Κούδας since you have been here for good amount of time now, it would be great if you consider accepting answers for your past questions!

Comment: It's not at all clear what the problem is. Anyway, you shouldn't load `MnSymbol`, that changes the appearance of *all* math symbols in shapes that clash with the text font.

Comment: @moewe sorry, wrong screenshot! I was hurried to go to work... I changed.

Comment: @Raaja I 'm sorry, I was working until now.

Comment: @KώσταςΚούδας If I compile your code, I get `&` where expected.

Comment: @egreg seriously??? I 'm not joking. What do you believe that is my problem? P.S.: I have problem with `paralist` package also.

Comment: @KώσταςΚούδας Neither I am joking. I see nothing that could explain a missing `&`, sorry. How are you compiling? What's your TeX distribution?

Comment: @egreg I use pdflatex and I compile "traditionally" using the texstudio button. Maybe I didn't understand your question about compiling.

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue. Please post your `.log`-file

Comment: @DG' I edited the post. I include the `log` files for both problems (`&` and `enumerate`). Thank's for your answer!

Comment: Mhhhh, as I say I get the expected output from your MWE. Your log file shows `Missing character: There is no & in font tcrm1000!`. The log file also suggests that your system is outdated, an update in user *and* admin mode might help (as always: an update directly before a deadline is risky). But I'm no font expert and this could be a different issue. BTW: The link to the second log file actually points to the the `.tex` file of the MWE, you may want to fix that. It might be nicer to combine both examples into one truly minimal MWE (is `paralist` needed or would `(i)` be enough?)

Comment: @moewe thank's a lot!!! The problem fixed when I update the miktex as an *admin* (as *user* I can't, an other error occurs, `copystart_admin.exe not found`...). Also I fix the main post, as you recommended. Thank's! **P.S.:** I need an easy way to enumerate with *i, ii, iii,...* or *I, II, III,...* or *α, β, γ,...*. Is it possible without `paralist`?

Comment: @KώσταςΚούδας Not sure, I guess that would make for a good new question. But maybe you can already find a solution if you search around a bit.