# problem with MiKTeX after updating

Tags: miktex, updating, miktex2.9, miktex-update, update

I use *Windows 10 Pro* and I updated *MiKTeX* for solving [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473464/missing-and-enumerate-numbering-by-using-mnsymbol-and-babel) problem. The problem now is that when I select:

- *MiKTeX package manager*, system says that `mpm_mfc_admin.exe` can't be found,
- *MiKTeX settings*, system says that `mo_admin.exe` can't be found,
- *MiKTeX update*, system says that `copystart_admin.exe` can't be found.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Miktex has changed a lot, there is now only one interface: the miktex console. I don't use miktex, so I'm not sure if the miktex update process would also have removed the menu entries from win10. Just to be on the safe side: do not d you update both as user and admin?

Comment: Nothing, the applications are really gone. You can remove the menu entries. If you don't already have one, add an link to the miktex console.

Comment: See also https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console: It is normal that the old programs are gone (one some installations the menu items for the old programs were removed or replaced with links to the Console, but there are reports that this did not happen for everybody). Just add a link to the Console to your menu and use it to manage your installation.7

Comment: So, *MiKTeX* don't exist any more? Is that are you saying? But how *latex* document is working? *MiKTeX console* is an other tex distribution? Sorry if I ask stupid questions...

Comment: @daleif should I update only as a *user* or only as an *admin*?

Comment: update as both to be on the safe side. Everything installed as user takes precedence over admin installed stuff. So if package A is installed in version 3 as user and version 6 as admin, you still get version 3.

Comment: MikTex is more than one program. The Miktex administrative interface (that you mentioned above) is no more, it is replaced by the MikTeX console. The latex programmes that are a part of the miktex distrubution remain the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In older versions of MiKTeX MiKTeX used several programs for administration (the one you named in your question).

The current version of MiKTeX has only one program for administration of MiKTeX (located in the apps of windows): MiKTeX Console:

[image: MiKTeX Console]

After calling it you have to choose to use it in admin or user mode (see red arrows in ithe image). That depends on your installation. If you have an admin installation (I have one) you have to update etc. first as admin, second as user.

The old programs for setting, package manager etc. you can found in the place marked with the big red circle. For example click on "Package" to get the package manager.

Refreshing the file data name and the font maps you can do by tasks (small red circle).

Comment: an other stupid question: how can I find *MiKTeX Console*? Do I have to reinstall *MiKTeX* to find it? Here (https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console) is saying that I have to search and click *MiKTeX Console* in the application launcher. I 've done it, but nothing appears. Thank's for your patience!

Comment: I decided to delete MiKTeX. I thought that a new beginning will help the situation...