# problem with MiKTeX and MiKTeX Console

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9, miktex-update, console

I had a problem with *MiKTeX* after updating (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473602/problem-with-miktex-after-updating)). I suggested to do something with *MiKTeX Console*, but I couldn't find anywhere *MiKTeX Console*. So I decided to reinstall *MiKTeX*. Then *MiKTeX Console* appeared for a little, and now I have again the [starting problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473602/problem-with-miktex-after-updating) also to *MiKTeX Console*:

When I select *MiKTeX Console* a message appears that is saying "windows are searching for `miktex-console.exe`." and suggests my to find this program by myself.

I tried to uninstall *MiKTeX* and reinstall it again, but I couldn't uninstall it.

What is going wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: And did you search for the exe yourself? It should be in the miktex folder in miktex/bin. Don't worry too much if an entry in the start menu disappears - windows looses them sometimes at updates; simply add it again.  And better stop this deinstalling and reinstalling - you can mess up your system quite a lot with it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried to find it by myself, but I get nothing... Also there is no miktex/bin. Maybe I mess up my system... This is the reason that I want to delete *MiKTeX* and reinstall it.

Comment: As you can start pdflatex, there musst be a bin folder from miktex somewhere. Open a command line and type `where pdflatex`, hopefully this give you a path. Or check in the log-file where book.cls is - the binaries are nearby.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer , you are right!!! I found it! The problem is that (1) I can't install packages (see: https://pastebin.com/ZAp6Fuei) and (2) the previews miktex remains in Windows start menu. Should I edit the main post or create a new question?

Comment: I have no problems to connect the miktex server, so whatever is blocking you is a local problem (proxy, firewall, overeager virus protection, something else ...). If you don't find the cause, you will have to install the packages through a local repository: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462216/2388

Comment: MikTeX will not install if the MikTeX folder is still there.  It typically has to be deleted (uninstall doesn't do it).

Comment: Thank you both! Finally I decide to delete MiKTeX. As usual I 'm full of questions...

Comment: Did this resolve your problem?

Comment: @standard,  yes it does. But I suppose that there exist an easier-better way.

Comment: MiKTex Console application(.exe) is in _C:\Users\lfcta\Documents\MiK_Tex_**\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-console** where the italic is the installed directory for the basic-miktex-23.4-x64 package. You can double click the app and start to check Updates or add the TEXMF root directories with Settings.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have to go to a specific fold in the operational system and delete the file Miktex console.lock. In w10 the path should be in C:/Users/your name/miktex-console.lock. This solve my same problem.