# problem with varwidth package

Tags: varwidth

I had a book that contains the `varwidth` package. Until now everything was OK, but finally this error appeared:

> Sorry, but "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe"
>   did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to
>   get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\HP
>   250\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\pdflatex.log

This problem appeared after [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473730/problem-with-miktex-and-miktex-console) problem. I don't know if they are related. What do you believe? How can I solve it?

[Here](https://pastebin.com/HK8jHxvt) is the `log`-file and this is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}

   text

\end{document}
```

Thank's in advanced!

Comment: No issues on TeX Live. Have you considered completely reinstalling MikTeX?

Comment: The error message doesn't say anything at at about the source of the problem. Does the file compile if you remove varwidth?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer , yes it compiles if I remove `varwidth` from the code I posted. I 'm saying "*from the code I posted*", because if I delete it from the book the error appears again. So, I suppose that an other package has problem too.

Comment: BTW: The log location you cite, seems odd, what is explicitly in the log for the document.

Comment: Then varwidth is probably not installed and miktex has problems to install it one the fly. Try to find the miktex-console and start it. Then search in the package list for varwidth and try to install it manually - if it doesn't work, you hopefully will at least get a better error message saying what doesn't work (e.g. proxy).

Comment: @daleif yes I tried to reinstall *MiKTeX*, but the system does not let me to delete the old version...

Comment: @daleif that's not the document log, but a log from miktex.

Comment: @daleif I select MiKTeX, because I use Windows. I heard that TeX Live is for Linux.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer the problem is that I can not open the `MiKTeX Console` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473730/problem-with-miktex-and-miktex-console).

Comment: I include the `log`-file.

Comment: TeXLive works on all systems including Windows. My point was just that you seem to have several problems with your MikTeX so perhaps it is an idea to uninstall the current miktex, and then reinstall it. Then perhaps the Miktex console will work properly.

Comment: Presumably `varwidth` is not installed on your system and something goes wrong when miktex attempts to install it on the fly.

Comment: @daleif I tried to uninstall the current *miktex* using the `Apps & Features` of Windows, but I couldn't.

Comment: Is your issue solved? How?

Comment: @Mensch I delete MiKTeX and reinstall it. The problem appeared after that (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473730/problem-with-miktex-and-miktex-console), as I said. I don't know if you have the same problem...

Answer (score 2):

With my current MiKTeX `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.4.12)` I can compile your give code without any errors or warnings ...

For me it seems your windows system is broken ...

Try the following steps:

1. Shutdown your windows, wait 1 minute (to get the hdd stop running) and start your computer.
2. Try to compile now again your given code. Result? It compiles: Good! Error message? Add the complete error message to your question please ...
3. If the error message is still there try to deinstall MiKTeX (use windows-key + s, then type `software` to find the windows tool to deinstall software. Choose `MiKTeX 2.9` to be deleted.). Check that the directories containing the MikTeX code with `MiKTeX 2.9` are deleted on your hdd. Check if you have still entries for MiKTeX 2.9in your registry ... Report the result in your question ...
4. Shutdown the computer, restart it after a minute (Yes windows loves to be rebooted ... Do not omit this step, that could result in bad results!).
5. If you have a registry cleaner run it to get rid of all entries for MiKTeX 2.9 in the registry (be careful, a wrong step here can completly ruin your windows with the result that you have to install windows OS new!!!)
6. Reboot the computer!
7. Download the current complete (netinstaller) MiKTeX install program from the homepage of MiKTeX and run it. Make sure it terminates normaly!
8. Reboot the computer.
9. Compile your given code again. No errors, okay. Errors: well I guess your system is so havily damaged you shout completly reinstall the computer ...

Comment: thanks for your answer! The problem has solved by deleting and reinstalling MiKTeX. So I don't know what would happen if I followed your advise.

Comment: @KώσταςΚούδας Well, if reinstalling already worked, great, then never change a running system :-) Then your older question is obsolete?

Comment: Yes, is obsolete...

Comment: @KώσταςΚούδας Can you vote to close it? If you want to delete it can you please delete the link in your question here to that obsolete question? Perhaps add a sentence describing the issue you had ....

Comment: I agree. What reason should I check?