# reinstalling MiKTeX

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9

After a few problems with *MiKTeX* (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473602/problem-with-miktex-after-updating), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473730/problem-with-miktex-and-miktex-console) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473732/problem-with-varwidth-package)) I decided to delete the current *MiKTeX* and reinstall it. I uninstalled *MiKTeX* from *MiKTeX Console*, but some folders named "miktex" (in several paths) continue to exist.

I tried to delete *MiKTeX* from `Apps & Features` of Windows, but I couldn't. The system can't find `miktex-conosle.exe`.

1. Should I remove these folders before installing the new *MiKTeX*? 
   `C:\Users\HP 250\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9` and  `C:\Users\HP 250\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX`. I prefer no, because I don't want to reinstall the fonts, but if it is necessery, I 'll do it.
2. If I finally have to remove them, can I delete these folders by using the traditional way "select all and then delete them"?
3. Should I uninstall also *TeXstudio*? I 've heard that *TeXstudio* has to be installed after *MiKTeX*.

Thank's in advanced!

Comment: If you don't reinstall all the packages/fonts, miktex won't perhaps know that they are installed and get confused. In theory you can import packages from another miktex with mpm but I have some doubts that your system is still in a state where this works.

Comment: 1.Set up a private (per-user) TeX installation. If you are reinstalling then there is good reason to follow the recommendations from MiKTeX **"It is highly recommended** that you choose a private installation. 
Setting up a shared (system-wide) installation requires administrator privileges and you should keep in mind that maintaining a shared installation can become complicated and error prone." There are open issues with an admin install such as #239  **64-bit MiKTeX-Console Admin on Win 10 exits without doing anything** #187 Win7 admin updating process buggy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system can't find `miktex-conosle.exe`.

The `miktex-conosle.exe` file does not exist, the name is `miktex-console.exe`. Some bad transcription somewhere.

Comment: Finaly I deleted these folders like there were simple files. Then I reinstalled MiKTeX and TeXstudio. Until now I didn't get problems! Thank you!!!